# Add bootstrap datetimepicker to TextBox inside a repeater in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio-2013, repeater

This is my code for repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterTrackingInformation" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterTrackingInformation_ItemDataBound">

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
            <tr>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>SentTo Date</th>
                <th>Approved Date</th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelDepartmentName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Department") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSentTo" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SentTo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxApproved" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReceivedFrom") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Everything is working fine. I need to add a bootstrap datetimepicker to every TextBox, I can do this with the following example, like this

```
$('#datetimepickerStartDate').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false
});
```

Here is my quesiton. How do I attach .datetimepicker inside a repeater using jQuery or JavaScript. I can NOT get at TextBoxSetTo because .NET generates different dynamic IDs.

I tried this

```
var rep = $('<%=RepeaterTrackingInformation.ClientID%>');
```

Comment: what if you do this `var rep = $('<%=RepeaterTrackingInformation.ClientID%>').val();` do you get the expected results..?

Comment: CssClass="datepicker"?

$('.datepicker').datetimepicker(...)

Comment: @B2K is that even possible can you do that in CssClass?

Comment: No you are misunderstanding. Moving it to an answer for formatting reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add CssClass inside your repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterTrackingInformation" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RepeaterTrackingInformation_ItemDataBound">

<HeaderTemplate>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th>SentTo Date</th>
            <th>Approved Date</th>
        </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelDepartmentName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Department") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSentTo" CssClass="datepicker"  runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SentTo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxApproved" CssClass="datepicker"  runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ReceivedFrom") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
</table>
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in javascript:

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false
});
```